# dart completion break the close parenthesis

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

If I manually type print(), then in the parenthesis, I type the word using completion, the correct parenthesis have gone away. like gif below

[image]

This doesn't happen if I type print() owing the completion of IDE. like this

[image]

Is this a bug?Otherwise how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an open issue about this in VS Code here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134013

One of the VS Code devs explains the issue:

> - typing `(` triggers suggest
> - now `)` is typed
> - the cursor is moved back and suggest is not cancelled
> - we now apply the logic that runs when text after the cursor has been typed (while suggest is active) and that removes the newly added text

It's caused by the fix for https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26012, which slightly conflicts with it (when completions include the parens).